# Adding scroll to nested container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get a container (`.widget2`) within a container (`.content`) to scroll and still maintain the borders.

For some reason, the inner container is scrolling past the bottom edge of the parent container, and the scrollbar doesn't render.

Here's a fiddle to show what I'm talking about:
https://jsfiddle.net/ggongon/kcyxz34L/1/

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#container {
  border: 6px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* position:absolute;
 top:10px; left:10px; right:10px; bottom:10px; */
}
#summary {
  height: 60px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
#content {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.widget {
  background: gray;
  border-radius: 12px;
  min-height: 30px;
}
.widget2 {
  overflow: auto;
}
.padbottom {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="summary">
    header section
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="widget padbottom">
      widget area
    </div>
    <div class="widget widget2">
      another widget area <br /><br>
      Problem:<br>
      1. this widget area scrolls past the bottom red border<br >
      2. How do i add a scroll in this section only and maintain the 10px padding within the content area <br><br><br>
sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>
sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>sdfasfd<br>
    </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .widget2 needs to grow to fill in 100% of the available area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `.widget2` scrollable, simply make the parent a flex container.

```
#content {
  padding:10px;
  border:2px solid blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;          /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kcyxz34L/2/)

Comment: @Michael_B - bada bing, bada boom!  works great.  thanks!!